# How can I fix the problem of a single PSU when use "samplics" in Python?

Tags: python, sampling, survey

I am using the package "samplics" to work with a complex survey. At the beginin I use the follow sequence:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyreadr
import samplics
from samplics.estimation import TaylorEstimator
from samplics.estimation import ReplicateEstimator
from samplics.utils import SinglePSUEst
```

In particular I'm interested in obtain

```
`total_1 =    TaylorEstimator('mean').estimate(y=tabla['TOT_1'],samp_weight=tabla['FAC_EXP'],stratum=tabla['EST_DIS'], psu=tabla['UPM_DIS'])`,
```

but the output is:

Problem with single PSU

[image]

I understand the issue, but I don't be able to find a path to include the option of single_psu = "singleton" or "skip" in the command.

I hope to find a way to include the option to fix the issue of a single primary sampling unit. Do you have any idea? : )

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to this question on the GitHub page for Samplics:
https://github.com/samplics-org/samplics/issues/33

In short, you can add the argument "single_psu" in the call of TaylorEstimator('mean').estimate as for example

```
`total_1 =    TaylorEstimator('mean').estimate(y=tabla['TOT_1'],samp_weight=tabla['FAC_EXP'],stratum=tabla['EST_DIS'], psu=tabla['UPM_DIS'], sigle_psu= SinglePSUEst.skip, )
```

Hope it helps.